# When deducing a parameter pack from a std::make_index_sequence, why can it not be used as default argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

To keep the template magic as deep in my code as possible I would like to use std::make_index_sequence as a default argument but this does not seem to compile and I don't quite understand why that is.

As an example take this case without default args, which compiles (Bare in mind this is a simplified example not my real use case):

```
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t... TIndicies>
std::size_t FunctNoDefaultArgs(std::index_sequence<TIndicies...>)
{
    return (TIndicies + ... + 0);
}

int main()
{
    return FunctNoDefaultArgs(std::make_index_sequence<5>{});
}
```

This works just fine.

So I wanted to move the std::make_index_sequence<5>{} to be a default argument and do the following:

```
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t... TIndicies>
std::size_t FunctDefaultArgs(std::index_sequence<TIndicies...> = std::make_index_sequence<5>{})
{
    return (TIndicies + ... + 0);
}

int main()
{
    return FunctDefaultArgs();
}
```

This does not compile in either MSVC, Clang or gcc. Could someone explain why?

[CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/EEaMvbY9h)

Answer (score 0):

Template parameter deduction is the first order of business here. You have to figure out ***what exactly*** are you calling, before you start worrying about its parameters.

```
FunctDefaultArgs();
```

Ok, what are the template parameters here? You can't deduce them. There's nothing to deduce. It's entirely possible that, for example, some particular set of template parameters will wind up at a template specialization that has completely different parameters, default or non-default.

Template parameters have to be deduced first, before anything is done.

Fortunately, the solution -- that effects the same result -- is trivial. It should be just an additional declaration/definition:

```
inline auto FunctNoDefaultArgs()
{
    return FunctNoDefaultArgs(std::make_index_sequence<5>{});
}
```

Comment: Function template specializations can’t be completely unrelated the way they can be for class templates, and they can’t have default arguments at all.

Comment: @DavisHerring is correct. There can only be one default value because function template specializations can't have default arguments nor can they be partial. Therefore in your initial example FunctDefaultArgs() there actually is something to deduce (or at least this is my thinking); the unique default from the initial, non-specialized template.